# Why is the highest power in a limit the only one that matters?

Tags: calculus

I have to do a project in calculus and I have to answer the question why is the highest power in a limit the only one that's important. For example if we have $$\frac{2x^3 + 4x^2 - 2x}{4x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x}$$ why do we only pay attention to $2x^3$ and $4x^3$?

Comment: $$\frac{2x^3+4x^2-2x}{4x^3-6x^2+11}=\frac{x^3 \left(2+\frac{4}{x}-\frac{2}{x^2}\right)}{x^3 \left(4-\frac{6}{x}+\frac{11}{x^3}\right)}$$

Comment: You mean, the only one that is important when we take a limit of a ratio of polynomials in $x$ as $x$ goes to infinity, right? Because in many other cases (such as rational function where $x$ approaches a finite value) the lower-order terms _do_ matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide numerator and denominator by the highest power of $x$ appearing in the denominator, each of these turns into a constant plus fractions that tend to zero as $x$ tends to infinity:
$$\frac{2x^3 + 4x^2 - 2x}{4x^3-6x^2 + 11x} = \frac{2 + \frac4x - \frac2{x^2}}{4-\frac6x + \frac{11}{x^2}}$$
You can see that only the leading coefficients matter in the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

You should consider what happens if the numerator has higher or lower degree than denominator.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be true if the limit was taken as $x \rightarrow \infty$. If instead the limit is taken as $x$ approaches some other value then it is not true. For example

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{2x + 7}{11x - 4} = -\frac{7}{4}$$

However, the highest power terms dominate the lower power terms as $x \rightarrow \infty$ so in that case you can ignore the lower power terms.

Even so, other terms might dominate the highest power terms. For example $3^x$ grows faster than $x^3$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ so if you had a $3^x$ term then that may dominate.